# Python, integer processing as string.

Tags: python, string, types, integer

Beginner here learning python. I'm having an issue processing the follwing code. I'm trying to compare numbers but I am getting an "unorderable type error". I don't understand why, as both numbers being compared are integers.

```
winning_number = 5

guess = input("Can you guess the lucky number.\nHint it's between 1 and 10!\n")

def compare(guess):
    if guess > winning_number:
        print ("Wrong, you're guess is too high")
    elif guess < winning_number:
        print ("Wrong, you're guess is too low")
    else:
        pass

compare(guess)
```

Comment: You may try using `guess = int(input("Can you guess the lucky number.\nHint it's between 1 and 10!\n"))`. From the code it seems that you are using Python3.x, and the `input()` returns a `str` in that case

Comment: Your else is also redundant

Comment: Ah! I see. Yes, I am using Pyhton3, and your tip worked! Thanks!